# Trouble getting correct element from index path in table view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to transfer the users information to another segue but when I select the user in the table view it shows another user's information, and not the one that it suppose to be.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowUser" {
            if let indexPath = followUsersTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? OtherUserProfile
                controller?.otherUser = user
                controller?.loggedInUser = loggedInUser

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have sections in your table view? In that case you might need to do something like this: usersArray[(indexPath.section + 1) * indexPath.row] To get the correct user

Comment: This is what i have for sections, i also have a filter function.

Comment: func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       
        return 1
    }

Comment: the filtering may be affecting, because other selected row can show different users information.

Comment: Yes, so im trying to reload the data every time the filter filters the username

Comment: Could you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? And how did you create your segue? This could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589630/xcode-passing-information-from-uitableviewcontroller-to-uiviewcontroller Also, could you clarify that `indexPath` is the correct one? And, check what's the value of `user`, and by printing `usersArray` give us the index of the supposed user you selected?

Comment: @Larme This is the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
  
    databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        
        let key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "uid")
        
        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid)
        {
            cell.frame.size.height = 0
        }

Comment: user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: but it is passing the information, that problem that Im having is that every time my search bar text updates the table view cells, it updates the name and subname, but it doesnt update the data from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should send your user in the didSelectRowAt delegate method. If not implemented, add the method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowUser", sender: user)

}
```

then in your prepare for segue add:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowUser" {
        let controller = segue.destination as? OtherUserProfile
        controller?.otherUser = sender as! YourUserClass
        controller?.loggedInUser = loggedInUser
    }
}
```

Remember to CHANGE the "YourUserClass" with the actual class of the user. Maybe if using firebase it is something like FIRUser.

Hope it helps and don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I know whats happening now, when my table view filters the users, it doesn't reload the data from the previous row, so if I have robert on the row 2, and i filter again, and lara goes to row 2. it will show robert's information if i select the row, i have to refresh the row every time it filters. How can I do that?

Comment: @GabrielTavares use either reloadSections or reloadData methods on the tableview instance.

Comment: should I use reload on my filter instance? every time it changes the text field value, should reload?

Comment: @GabrielTavares Yes. every time the underlying data structure is manipulated in any way (either by adding or removing elements), you should call the reload method so that the UI reflects the current state. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, but where should i call the reload method? when the search bar text changes?