# Wrong information displayed on SecondViewController when table row clicked

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm attempting for the first time to build a tableView that's grouped rather than plain but having issues with the information that is shown when a cell is tapped being incorrect.

First I've created an array and this array is used to give my groups their titles. Next I have an array that holds 4 more arrays each holding 8 objects apart from the last one which only has 1 and these 4 arrays are my sections for the groups.

When the app is run the group table shows up exactly as it should but when you click a particular row it may display the information that should be for a different row. I am removing some of the objects from the arrays simply to make the code shorter for you to see here.

Rune:

```
import UIKit

struct Rune {
    var runeName: String
    var runeImage: UIImage
    var runeDescription: String

}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var runeTitle = [["Freyr/Freya's Aett"], ["Heimdall's Aett"], ["Tyr's Aett"], ["Additional Runes"]]

    let runes = [[Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Fehu.png"))!, runeDescription: "(F: Domestic cattle, wealth.) Possessions won or earned, earned income, luck. Abundance, financial strength in the present or near future. Sign of hope and plenty, success and happiness. Social success. Energy, foresight, fertility, creation/destruction (becoming).\n\n Fehu Reversed or Merkstave: Loss of personal property, esteem, or something that you put in effort to keep. It indicates some sort of failure. Greed, burnout, atrophy, discord. Cowardice, stupidity, dullness, poverty, slavery, bondage."),
                  Rune(runeName: "Wunjo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Wunjo.png"))!, runeDescription: "(W or V: Joy.) Joy, comfort, pleasure. Fellowship, harmony, prosperity. Ecstasy, glory, spiritual reward, but also the possibility of going \"over the top\". If restrained, the meaning is general success and recognition of worth.\n\n Wunjo Reversed or Merkstave: Stultification, sorrow, strife, alienation. Delirium, intoxication, possession by higher forces, impractical enthusiasm. Raging frenzy, berzerker.")],

                 [Rune(runeName: "Hagalaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Hagalaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "(H: Hail.) Wrath of nature, destructive, uncontrolled forces, especially the weather, or within the unconscious. Tempering, testing, trial. Controlled crisis, leading to completion, inner harmony. Hagalaz Merkstave (Hagalaz cannot be reversed, but may lie in opposition): Natural disaster, catastrophe. Stagnation, loss of power. Pain, loss, suffering, hardship, sickness, crisis."),
                  Rune(runeName: "Sowilo", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Sowilo.png"))!, runeDescription: "(S: The sun.) Success, goals achieved, honor. The life-force, health. A time when power will be available to you for positive changes in your life, victory, health, and success. Contact between the higher self and the unconscious. Wholeness, power, elemental force, sword of flame, cleansing fire. Sowilo Merkstave (Sowilo cannot be reversed, but may lie in opposition): False goals, bad counsel, false success, gullibility, loss of goals. Destruction, retribution, justice, casting down of vanity. Wrath of god.")],

                 [Rune(runeName: "Tiwaz", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Tiwaz.png"))!, runeDescription: "(T: Tyr, the sky god.) Honor, justice, leadership and authority. Analysis, rationality. Knowing where one's true strengths lie. Willingness to self-sacrifice. Victory and success in any competition or in legal matters.\n\n Tiwaz Reversed or Merkstave: One's energy and creative flow are blocked. Mental paralysis, over-analysis, over-sacrifice, injustice, imbalance. Strife, war, conflict, failure in competition. Dwindling passion, difficulties in communication, and possibly separation."),
                  Rune(runeName: "Othala", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Othala.png"))!, runeDescription: "(O: Ancestral property.) Inherited property or possessions, a house, a home. What is truly important to one. Group order, group prosperity. Land of birth, spiritual heritage, experience and fundamental values. Aid in spiritual and physical journeys. Source of safety, increase and abundance.\n\n Othala Reversed or Merkstave: Lack of customary order, totalitarianism, slavery, poverty, homelessness. Bad karma, prejudice, clannishness, provincialism. What a man is bound to.")],

                  [Rune(runeName: "Blank Rune", runeImage: UIImage(named: ("Blank.png"))!, runeDescription: "There is no historical support for a \"Blank Rune\" in runic divination. It was invented in the 1980's. It should not be used in a rune casting. If you bought a rune set with a blank piece, save it in case you lose another rune piece, but don't use it in rune casting.")]]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return runes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return runes[section].count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure the cell...

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;

    let item = runes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = item.runeImage
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.runeName
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return String(describing: runeTitle[section][0])
}

var clickedIndex = 0
var section = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.clickedIndex = indexPath.row
    self.section =  indexPath.section

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {

        let runeArray = runes[section][clickedIndex]
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationVC.selectedRune = runeArray
    }
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

}
```

SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedRune: Rune!

    @IBOutlet weak var runeNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var runeDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        runeNameLabel.text = selectedRune.runeName
        runeImage.image = selectedRune.runeImage
        runeDescriptionLabel.text = selectedRune.runeDescription
    }

}
```

Comment: Related: [Xcode: Passing Information from UITableViewController to UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589630/xcode-passing-information-from-uitableviewcontroller-to-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Hi @NiravD I had attempted something similar to this code with exactly the same outcome I'm having now and I'm unsure why that is, I had used these two lines: let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            destinationVC.selectedRune = runeArray[(indexPath?.row)!] but still the same result. Any Ideas?

Comment: Edit your question with your code that you are trying also how you have created segue, is it from `UITableViewCell` or from `ViewController`?

Comment: Code updated in my question and I ctrl dragged from the cell

Comment: You are having 2D array so it should be like `if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {  destinationVC.selectedRune =  runes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return runes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return runes[section].count
    }
```

So rather than getting indexPath.row, you also need to get the current selected section. E.g.,

```
self.clickedIndex = indexPath.row 
self.section = indexPath.section
```

And then your selected runArray would be

```
let runeArray = runes[section][clickedIndex]
```

**UPDATE**

Your problem is the `prepare:forSegue` gets called before `tableview:didSelectRowAt` is called. You should use either of them rather than both. The following snippet shows how to navigate to the other view controller using `navigationtroller.pushViewController`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        section = indexPath.section
        clickedIndex = indexPath.row
        let runeArray = runes[section][clickedIndex]

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController else { return}
        destinationVC.selectedRune = runeArray
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)        
}
```

Remember to set you `Storyboard ID` to **SecondVC** or whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: this is almost working correctly using your changes, just one little bug to iron out.  When I click on a row in a new section for the first time I get the wrong data but every row I click after that is perfect, it is always the same wrong data, for example I click a row in section two it will give me the first entry of section one, If I click a row in section three it will give me the first entry of section two. Apart from this it works perfect. If this can be resolved that's the full issue fixed thankfully

Comment: So your `runArray` in fact is not an array but it's an instance. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Every time I start the app with my new updated code (see edit above) regardless what row I click on I get section[0] clickedIndex[0] and then when I click back and click on another row it will show the data for the previously clicked row, it looks like this is doing this because my section and clickedIndex variables are initially set to 0 I tried changing it to var section: Int! and var clickedIndex: Int! but this crashes my app. I'm confused whats going wrong here

Comment: It's because your `segue` func get called before the `didSelectRowAt` does. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is:
 1. Make an item object in table view cell (In YourtableViewCell.h and YourtableViewCell.m).
 2. Then assign that item in the cell (In cellForRowAtIndex method)
 3. Then in

> didSelectRowAt

4. Now you can get that item by that selected cell.

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable for indexpath.section 
initialize it in didSelectRow

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)           {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" 
{

     let runeArray = runes[ 
let item = runes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] ]// variable runeArray is the child array from runes
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationVC.selectedRune = runeArray[indexpath.section ]// Now choose an actual Rune object from the array by index.    
    }
```