# Pass data depends on the button in tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a TableView where I display all my data and each cell might have 1-2 buttons. I read many topics and understand how to add target for each button through my ViewController. Since these buttons will be forwarded to the same VC and display images, I have the following code. In my TableViewCell subclass I have 2 buttons

```
class CODetailsTicketCell: UITableViewCel {

      var onButtonTapped: (() -> Void)? = nil

      @IBAction func firstBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
          if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped {
              onButtonTapped()
          }
         print("First button was pressed")

     }

      @IBAction func secondBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
          if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped {
             onButtonTapped()
          }
          print("Second button was pressed")
     }
}
```

In my ViewController in cellForRowAt indexPath I have the following code

```
let message = messages[indexPath.row]

if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "COTicketsCell", for: indexPath) as? CODetailsTicketCell {
    cell.configureCell(openTickets: message)
    cell.onButtonTapped = {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toImageVC", sender: message)
     } 

     return cell
```

In order to pass the data through segue I use the following code in prepareForSegue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toImageVC" {
        let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        if let targetController = navigationController?.topViewController as? ImageVC {
            if let data = sender as? OpenTicketsData {
                targetController.loadImageURL = URL(string: data.firstImageUrl)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working FINE but I can't check for button tag in prepareForSegue. Basically, currently both buttons send the same data

```
targetController.loadImageURL = URL(string: data.firstImageUrl)
```

How can I pass data based on the button pressed? I tried to do something like this but seems it's wrong and not working.

```
let button = sender as? UIButton
if let data = sender as? OpenTicketsData {
   if button?.tag == 1 {
      targetController.loadImageURL = URL(string: data.firstImageUrl)
   } else if button?.tag == 2 {
      targetController.loadImageURL = URL(string: data.secondImageUrl)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either separate it into 2 different events or

```
class CODetailsTicketCell: UITableViewCell {

      var onButtonTapped: ((_ sender: UIButton) -> Void)? = nil

      @IBAction func firstBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
          if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped {
              onButtonTapped?(sender)
          }
         print("First button was pressed")

     }

      @IBAction func secondBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
          if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped {
              onButtonTapped(sender)
          }
          print("Second button was pressed")
     }
}
```

In your assignment of the `onButtonTapped`, remember to add `[weak self]` if you ever use `self` to avoid the retain cycle.

```
cell.onButtonTapped = { [weak self] sender in
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do other thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response but could please explain in more details how it will solve the problem? I didn't check this yet but I don't want just copy and paste the code.

Comment: As you already set `tag` to your 2 buttons and you use the same event for them, in `onButtonTapped` you need to pass the button (sender) in as an argument. By doing so, when you assign an actual function in the view controller you know which button has been tapped.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to check for tag in cellForIndexPath and this is not a problem to perform different actions for multiple buttons. The problem is that I don't know how to do it in prepareForSegue in order to display the data based on the button.

Comment: Regarding to using `prepare:forSegue` or `onButtonTapped` to navigate to another view controller, you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44779326/7113238. It's a very similar case that I've explained why you should you either of them.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. I'll check and update my question if any questions.